# How does one set the default property access on a class?

Tags: python

Python (2.7) newbie here.  What I want to do is have a reference to an instance of a class return a given property as the 'default' without having to specify that property.  I want to do this because the vast majority of the time I refer to an instance, it is to access this one property.

For example, let's say I have a couple of classes to describes a book:

```
class book:
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = ''
        self.author = ''
        self.page = {}

class page:
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = ''
        self.length = 0
```

I create an instance and fill it with the contents of a book like so:

```
...    
war_and_peace = book()
page_count = 0
for page in pages:  #Let's say pages is a list of strings each of a page of the book
    pagenum += 1
    war_and_peace.page[pagenum] = page
```

Now in the remainder of the program, 99.9% of the time I reference the text of the pages.  So to make my life a little easier, I would like to be able to reference a page using:

```
if 'Anna' in war_and_peace[15]:
    ...
```

instead of

```
if 'Anna' in war_and_peace.page[15].text:
    ...
```

How might I go about this?  (Sorry if this has been answered; I am probably using the wrong search terms!)

Thanks!

Comment: this `for page in pages: pagenum += 1 war_and_peace.page[pagenum] = page` is better written as `for pagenum,page in enumerate(pages): foo.page[pagenum] = page`

Comment: Cool!  Thanks. I'd seen this construct before but had not appreciated it.

Comment: Keep in mind that `pagenum` will start at `0` so you'll need `foo.page[pagenum+1] = page`.

Comment: I just learned you can also make `enumerate` start at any number, so `enumerate(pages, start=1)` works a little more cleanly.  I wound up having to do this because the real application used the page number in a denominator and it blows up if page defaults to 0 (since none of my books have a page 0).  Thanks again for the tip!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A [`__getitem__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) override on `book` will give you this:

```
def __getitem__(self, item):
    return self.page[item].text
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks so much.  The Python Data Model page is a dense but powerful read, and I missed this one.  I'll probably have to read that page every day for a week before it sinks in.